# Echoing HTML with PHP causing syntax error due to quotes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js with PHP and I'm trying to make a GET request which then returns an HTML/knockout form. The reason for doing this is because the form will be used by others, and rather than copying/pasting a rather large chunk of code, it's simply less code just to make a request to my server which returns the HTML/knockout.

```
//code on another server to request form from my server
$.ajax({
      //request here
    })
</script>

<div id = "update_div">
        <!--form data goes here when received -->
</div>
```

Now, this is the code on my server. Where the issue lies is that since I have to echo using php and I'm returning text, I need to use either a single or double quote around the text I'm echoing. However, I'm using knockout.js and a knockout.js validation addon which requires both single and double quotes, essentially canceling out the quotes wrapping the echo.

For example,

```
 <?
    if($_GET['something']){
       echo '
         <tr>
            <td>Full Name</td>
            <td><span data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false}">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: fullName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/></span></td> 
            <td data-bind="validationMessage: fullName"></td>
        </tr>
       ';
     }
 ?>
```

The line that is specifically causing the problem is

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: fullName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/></span></td>
```

Which the error returned is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'afterkeydown' (T_STRING)
```

When I echo I use single quotes because I want to return it as text, however, within that I need to use single and double quotes for different elements. IS there a way around this?

Comment: You need to escape the single quotes around it like `\'afterkeydown\'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this -

```
<?
    if($_GET['something']){
       echo '
         <tr>
            <td>Full Name</td>
            <td><span data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false}">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: fullName, valueUpdate: \'afterkeydown\'"/></span></td> 
            <td data-bind="validationMessage: fullName"><center></center></td>
        </tr>
       ';
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: `data-bind="value: fullName, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"` would break HTML validation. I think you mean `data-bind="value: fullName, valueUpdate: \'afterkeydown\'"`

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

you need to escape them

```
echo '
     <tr>
        <td>Full Name</td>
        <td><span data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false}">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: fullName, valueUpdate: \'afterkeydown\'"/></span></td> 
        <td data-bind="validationMessage: fullName"><center></center></td>
    </tr>
   ';
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is an hypertext preprocessor, you can write raw HTML without using `echo` [and getting such quote nightmares]:

```
<?php if($_GET['something']): ?>

 <tr>
    <td>Full Name</td>
    <td><span data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false }">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: fullName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/></span></td> 
    <td data-bind="validationMessage: fullName"><center></center></td>
</tr>

<?php endif; ?>
```

[see how SO syntax highlighting works fine now!]

BTW, `<center>` tag is deprecated since HTML 4.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware this method could be done. I would accept, however, pXL beat you to a response.

Answer (score 1):

whenever you have text like this:

`TEXT 'LIKE' THIS`

and you want to echo it, just prefix the ' with a \:

`echo 'asdfadsf\'asdfasdf'`

so in your case:

```
echo '
 <tr>
    <td>Full Name</td>
    <td><span data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false}">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: fullName, valueUpdate: \'afterkeydown\'"/></span></td> 
    <td data-bind="validationMessage: fullName"><center></center></td>
</tr>
```

';